# WPF DataGrid Double-Click Exception

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Long-time WinForms programmer relatively new to WPF. I'm databinding a DataGrid in Code-Behind using a SQL Query. I reuse the DataGrid because I'm using Ribbon Tabs and reload different data in the grid dependent on the Tab selected. So binding to a static resource is not possible.
I'm trying to open a new window on a double-click event but get the following exceeption - "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs'."
This used to be a simple thing in WinForms. My code is as follows:

```
Try
        Dim StrRow As DataRowView = MainDataGrid.SelectedItem
        Dim CellValue As String = StrRow.Row(0).ToString()
        'MsgBox(CellValue)
        e.Handled = True
        Dim EventDetails = New EventDetails()
        EventDetails.Show()
        OpenEventDetailsWindow()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No Event No.for this Event")
    End Try
```

The messagebox shows the proper string (first cell value of selected row and the new window actually pops up right before the exception is thrown. I've seen plenty of posts that say this method should work but it doesn't. I've been so far unsuccessful in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably show the xaml of how you setup this double click event. Hard to answer when you really aren't showing anything but a try catch event somewhere in the bowels of your code.  That said, you should probably be using a command binding.

Comment: That is the entirety of the double-click routine. I've tried a couple different ways to bind this command, but here is the current XAML...
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="MainDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"/>
</Style>
Again, it doesn't appear to be the binding method but the exception happens trying to open the new window.